# When is the best time to drink PHD Diet Whey Protein

Tags: diet, weight-loss, protein-shakes, burn-fat, diet-tools

I am looking to burn fat and gain muscle during my sports off season. I gym about 3 times a week, and take PHD diet whey.

I have one in the morning and one after going to the gym in the evening.

When is the best time to take another shake on non-gym days?

Comment: Why do you think the timing matters on non-gym days?

Comment: because the aim of this particular shake is to keep up the metabolism rate and acts as a meal replacement. Should this replace a mid afternoon snack, an evening meal, or a later afternoon meal? (based on 6 small meals a day)

Comment: Unless you are specifically calorie or protein deficient, I'd advise eating real food instead, especially on off days.

Comment: @GraemeHutchison nutrition timing is not that important except for the protein source around workouts (as that anabolic window opens up). Take it whenever you feel like on non-gym days would be my recommendation.

Comment: @johnP, I have a busy lifestyle which makes planning meals and nutrition hard. Taking a shake is my preferred method. This question is about when to take them.

Comment: @GraemeHutchison - Bull. I'm out the door at 5:30a for work, off at 4, workouts/physical therapy and homework until 8ish, then an hour or two before bed. Take two hours one time during the week, chop up veggies and broil/bbq a few chicken breasts, pork chops, etc. Put it all in baggies/tupperware, and grab and go. Aside from the protein, if you get a lot of your meals from shakes, you are also missing out on a lot of micronutrients and elements to help absorption of vitamins and minerals. You just don't get the same quality of nutrition from a shake as you do real food. Do your body a favor.

Comment: @johnP Well done you, however you are not helping at all. Thank you.

Comment: @GraemeHutchison - Actually, yes, I am helping. You just don't like the answer. There is more to real food than there is in a protein supplement, plus you have to worry about the actual absorption and utilization in the absence of other nutrients/vitamins/minerals.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why all the answers saying timing doesn't matter are being downvoted.

There is no link between time of protein ingestion in relation to working out that has any substantial effect. Please see [this paper.](http://www.jissn.com/content/pdf/1550-2783-10-53.pdf)

Comment: Probably because they are low quality, one liner answers. Also, if you could summarize/recap the main points of the study, it would help your answer stay valid if the link ever breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You drink protein shake to complement your protein intake, regardless of training days or times, unless you are very experienced timing doesn't really matter.

Comment: How did get downgraded? timing matters least when intake isn't measured. especially for beginners

Answer (score -3):

I think that you are absolutely on the right track as far as when you are taking them on your workout days.

As far as non workout days go, the best thing to do, IMO, is to have one in the morning within a half hour of waking up and if you want a second one, go for it. I honestly don't think the timing is that important. You really need to listen to what your body wants if you are craving more food. DO you want carbs, sugar, etc... There are healthy foods that will solve those needs. If your body wants protein have another shake. I don't think that you will be getting full benefits from a nutritional shake just by taking it because you think you need to. They are best in the morning and after working out.

Comment: I wonder how the body tells someone they are craving for some specific nutrient.

Comment: You know that is one that I can't answer but often times when i am craving carbs or sugar, I will have some fruit or broccoli (for example) instead of bread, or candy, your body naturally wants fat and sugar you just have to find the healthy substitutes

Comment: -1 @DeanKarasinski All the overweight people crave nutrient dense fatty sugary food because it is an addiction like a drug. Telling someone to listen to their cravings is ridiculous advice. Face palm!

Comment: If you read what I actually wrote, you need to feed your body what it wants. It tells you for a reason. If you want fat east some almonds, if you want sugar eat some fruit. Dont go eat a stick of butter and a donut. You HAVE to listen to your body or you will never make on your diet.